# Why is removeEventListener not properly working in my Nuxt app?

Tags: javascript, node.js, vue.js, nuxt.js

The component below renders when there is a search result on my app, and it checks if the user scrolling is at the bottom of the page. The code works well at first, but after navigating out of the page and returning back to the page and scrolling is where I then get the error

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'getBoundingClientRect' of undefined
> at VueComponent.handleScroll

```html
<template>
    <div class="grid-card-layout scrolling-component" ref="scrollComponent">
        <slot/>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
    methods: {
        handleScroll() {
            let element = this.$refs.scrollComponent
            if (element.getBoundingClientRect().bottom < window.innerHeight) {
                window.removeEventListener('scroll', this.handleScroll);
                return this.$emit("load-more");
            }
        },
        mountOnScroll() {
            window.addEventListener('scroll', this.handleScroll);
        }
    },
    mounted() {
        window.addEventListener('scroll', this.handleScroll);
        // Start observing the target node for configured mutations
        const observer = new MutationObserver(this.mountOnScroll);
        observer.observe(this.$refs.scrollComponent, {
            attributes: true, 
            childList: true, 
            characterData: true
        });
    },
    unmounted() {
        window.removeEventListener('scroll', this.handleScroll);
    }
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`unmounted` is a Vue3 lifecycle: https://v3.vuejs.org/guide/composition-api-lifecycle-hooks.html

In Vue2, the hooks are `beforeDestroy` and `destroyed` as shown in the API: https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#beforeDestroy

Here is the lifecycle diagram for Vue2: https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/instance.html#Lifecycle-Diagram

[image]